# Best thinkflow to make a Chemistry game in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, chemistry

So, as mentioned I'm doing some Flash this semester...I think I'd know how to do this in Python, with classes and all, but in AS3, everything is just so...detached.

I want to build a short chemistry game. You have 4 elements, fire, earth, wind and spirit, but the water is missing, the point is to make water. So you have on the stage, a fire_mc, a wind_mc, an earth_mc, a spirit_mc and the pot_mc. Clicking them adds a drop of them in the pot.

You have to put elements in there in a very specific order, but if you mess up, the count resets and you have to restart. The order is fire, spirit, earth, fire, spirit, wind. (very arbitrary at the moment, but let's say it's like that)

How would I make that in AS3?

(these tags are there to help people that want to build this specific kind of game)

This is my current code.

```
stop();
lvln.text="Phase 3 - Bargaining";
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

const WIDTH:int=50;
const HEIGHT:int=50;
const SEPX:int=50;

var fireb:firebtn=new firebtn();
var spiritb:spiritbtn=new spiritbtn();
var earthb:earthbtn=new earthbtn();
var windb:windbtn=new windbtn();
var combo:Array=new Array();
var truecombo:Array=[fireb,spiritb,spiritb,windb,earthb];
var lastElm=combo[combo.length-1];

firebb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fire1);
windbb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wind1);
earthbb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, earth1);
spiritbb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spirit1);

function add1(clip:DisplayObject)
{
    if (combo.length > 6) 
    {
        combo.shift();
        combo.push(clip);
        reorder();
    }
}

function reorder()
{
   for(var i:int = 0; i < combo.length; i++)
   {
       combo[i].x = i * 50;
   }
}

function fire1(e:MouseEvent)
{
    lastX+=SEPX;
    twist.gotoAndPlay(2);
    var fireb:firebtn=new firebtn();
    stage.addChild(fireb);
    add1(fireb);
    fireb.width=WIDTH;
    fireb.height=HEIGHT;
    fireb.x=lastX;
    fireb.y=lastY;
    pop.play();
}

function wind1(e:MouseEvent)
{
    lastX+=SEPX;
    twist.gotoAndPlay(2);
    var windb:windbtn=new windbtn();
    stage.addChild(windb);
    add1(fireb);
    windb.width=WIDTH;
    windb.height=HEIGHT;
    windb.x=lastX;
    windb.y=lastY;
    pop.play();
}

function earth1(e:MouseEvent)
{
    lastX+=SEPX;
    twist.gotoAndPlay(2);
    var earthb:earthbtn=new earthbtn();
    stage.addChild(earthb);
    add1(fireb);
    earthb.width=WIDTH;
    earthb.height=HEIGHT;
    earthb.x=lastX;
    earthb.y=lastY;
    pop.play();
}


function spirit1(e:MouseEvent)
{
    lastX+=SEPX;
    twist.gotoAndPlay(2);
    var spiritb:spiritbtn=new spiritbtn();
    stage.addChild(spiritb);
    combo.push(spiritb);
    spiritb.width=WIDTH;
    spiritb.height=HEIGHT;
    spiritb.x=lastX;
    spiritb.y=lastY;
    pop.play();
}
```

Comment: You may want to start with http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn/how-to-learn-flash-and-as3-for-game-development/ as then you can get a better idea how to start.

Comment: Actually I have a fair understanding of AS3...problem is this thing goes a bit beyond my capabilities, so maybe some hinting could give me some help...for example I can find my way through many problems in AS3 (with some google of course) but this idea seems so...complex.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.
So you have 4 element. Make a button/MovieClip for each of them(when you click on one of them the pot fill with it) that's the animation you have to deal with. But to check if combination is correct use this code

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    var combination:Array=new Array(); //Array that loads elements being clicked
    var clength:Number = 0; // combination length for making water
    var truecombination:Array=new Array();  // Array that holds combination for making water
    truecombination.push("fire"); //first element
    truecombination.push("wind"); //second element
    truecombination.push("spirit"); //third element
    truecombination.push("fire"); //fourth element
    truecombination.push("wind"); // fifth element
    truecombination.push("earth"); //sixt element(you can go for more elements in your combination but remember to change the clength variable)

    //adding event listeners for elemnt buttons
    fire_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fclick);
    wind_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wclick);
    spirit_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sclick);
    earth_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eclick);

    //you can also add animation labels to the functions below to make the game more interesting
    function fclick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        combination.push("fire");
            clength+=1;
    }
    function wclick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        combination.push("wind");
            clength+=1;
    }
    function sclick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        combination.push("spirit");
            clength+=1;
    }
    function eclick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        combination.push("earth");
            clength+=1;
    }

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);//making a loop function that checks the combination
    function loop(e:Event):void
    {
        if (truecombination.length => 6) //waiting for player to enter his combination
        {
            if (combination[clength-6] == "fire" && combination[clength-5] == "wind" && combination[clength-4] == "spirit" && combination[clength-3] == "fire" && combination[clength-2] == "wind" && combination[clength-1] == "earth") //checking if combination is true
            {

                trace("You Won");
            }
            else // and if it is not true...
            {
                //trace("You Lose");

            }
        }
    }
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Seems like what I'm thinking, but what about the lose condition? There is no real loss..I want the Array to update all the time with the last 6 clicks, and if they match the "truecombo" then you win. Is there a way to keep the last 6 clicks and when a new one is clicked, then remove the oldest?

Comment: No...what I'm saying is, the combination should ALWAYS update, always only keeping the last 6 clicks, not wait for 6 clicks then zero them out. I know about the "shift" but it kinda doesn't work. Also I want the miniversions to reposition themselves. Please see my new edited question.

Comment: I edited my code again. Now the computer always fill combination Array and check for each 6 elements in a row if combination is true until it is true. I used my code because it is easier for me to edit but the point is that you get my idea for making a game.Good Luck!